# How to configure SSL through GoDaddy using AWS Certificate Manager?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, https, certificate-authority, godaddy

I created an SSL cert with AWS Certificate Manager. I followed the instructions provided to create a CNAME in GoDaddy, but my AWS Certificate status is still "Pending validation" six hours later.

I configured godaddy as such:

```
CNAME
host: _randomStringFromAWS.mydomain.com
points to: _randomStringFromAWS.acm-validations.aws
```

The "host" came from the AWS "Record Name" field and the "points to" came from the AWS "Record Value" field.

Should the "host" in GoDaddy be filled with the "Domain Name" field from AWS (eg. *.mydomain.com)?

Can AWS Certificate Manager be used with GoDaddy for SSL?

Comment: *Should the "host" in GoDaddy be filled with the "Domain Name"* Probably not.  It depends on the UI, but most likely, it should just be `_randomStringFromAWS` on the left-hand side.  Otherwise, you're creating a record for `_randomStringFromAWS.example.com.example.com`.

Comment: The above comment seems to be the right answer. More cases [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=913098)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AWS ACM certificates can only be used to secure connections for specific AWS services such as CloudFront CDN or ELBs as documented here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/acm-services.html.

Note that it's possible to have your DNS zone hosted outside of Amazon (Go Daddy in your example) and still utilize Amazon services including ACM.